# facebook comment box in asp.net using repeater

Tags: asp.net, row, repeater, facebook-comments

I have a repeater which has two columns one column contains label and another has textbox.

on enter data in the text box it should show as label and another textbox in the same row should appear.i am getting a text box but not able to do as said above.Please help me.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepDetails_ItemDataBound" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="border: 0px solid #df5015; width: 100%">
            <tr style="background-color: White; color: White">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>Atrributes</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #EBEFF0; height: 50px;" >
            <td >
                <table style="background-color: #EBEFF0; border: 0px dotted #df5015; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px;">
                    <tr style="height: 20px;">
                        <td style="width: 30%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAttributeName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AttirbuteName") %>' Font-Bold="true" /></td>
                        <td id="textboxId" style="width: 70%">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAttributeNameDef" runat="server" ToolTip='<%#Eval("AttirbuteDefination") %>' Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: "Unclear" what you are asking.

Comment: let me know where it is unclear

Comment: I have a repeater which has two columns one column contains label and another has textbox.
on data enter in the text box it should show as label with the enteredata and same data in the textbox should clear .i am getting a text box but not able to do as said above.Please help me.same like facebook comment box

Comment: http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/buGiB  see this comment box

Comment: @user3588674 thank youv ery much but the on add it should add o the above panel\

Comment: @user3588674 if i add a comment and click add that should add to the above panel.

Comment: I gave you design not implementing code..

Comment: @user3588674 i need an implemented code or an glimpse of how to implement

Comment: ok..Save the text box value then render it in comment panel...just like when load grid view...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/4ts8q95q/2/ done using jquery..

Comment: @user3588674  this needs to done in repeatercontrol in the row

Answer (score 0):

You can do using repeater like this way **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/4ts8q95q/3/)**

```
<div class="detailBox">
    <div class="titleBox">
      <label>Comment Box</label>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="commentBox">

        <p class="taskDescription">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="actionBox">
        <asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="commentList" id="listchat">
            <li>
                <div class="commenterImage">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/6" />
                </div>
                <div class="commentText">
                    <p class="">Hello this is a test comment.</p> <span class="date sub-text">on March 5th, 2014</span>

                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        <div class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtcomment" placeholder="Your comments" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="postcomment">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: though the above fiddle example works comments gets losted when postback also all the comments should save in database row wise.

Comment: Dude you need to bind the data to repeater after that only you will get the result...